# Formatted xml document type in scala

Tags: xml, scala, format

I need to format an xml node and send it as an output with `xml.Document` format. The code that I use to format is the following:

```
val xmlNode = <csl><Scale><amount>Constant(20.0)</amount><Stock><identifier>goog</identifier></Stock></Scale></csl>
val pp = new PrettyPrinter(80, 2)
val formattedNode = pp.format(xmlNode)
```

To change it into a Document format, I try to do something like this:

```
doc = new Document()
doc.docElem = formattedNode
```

Obviously, it gives a compilation error as the type of the `formattedNode` is a `String` while `docElem` needs an XML node. How do I get a formatted XML node into a XML `Document` type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I can do something like this:

```
val xmlNode = XML.loadString(<csl><Scale><amount>Constant(20.0)</amount><Stock><identifier>goog</identifier></Stock></Scale></csl>)
val pp = new PrettyPrinter(80, 4)
val formattedNode = XML.loadString(pp.format(xmlNode))
doc = new Document()
doc.docElem = formattedNode
```